# Ubuntu 16.04 - Wifi Disconnection - Script To Fix

Tags: networking, wireless, scripts, network-manager

Randomly (every few days), the wifi disconnects (USB adapter). Issuing this command fixes it:

`sudo service network-manager restart`

Logging into it manually to issue this command is annoying. How can I find out that the network is down and issue this command? I am thinking of scheduling something to ping an IP and if that fails then issue the above command. But my knowledge is limited. Appreciate any help or nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

My `bash` script https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic.git - "Watch for (WiFi) network going down, then do a user-specified thing to fix it."

should help